# Swift Stevia + UICollectionView self sizing Cells issues

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview

I've spent a few hours figuring out why Stevia and self-sizing cells have terrible sizing issues. It seems that the constraints are conflicting with the auto-sizing. Causing the cell to snap to the wrong size.

Answer (score 1):

So after a lot of trial and error. This is what finally worked.

1. Set `UICollectionViewFlowLayout:estimatedItemSize` to `UICollectionViewFlowLayout.automaticSize`. No other setting seems to work.
2. Set `UICollectionViewCell` width and size explicitly to the target cell size.
3. Do not rely on `contentView` as your view container. Instead, add a new and also size that view to your target cell size.